# Is there a way to stop code from running if certain conditions are met?

Tags: r, r-markdown

first time posting here. Since a couple of months, I have been using R at work to send a daily e-mail about sales: however, sometimes there is a problem with the source data and the information contained in the e-mail is not correct.

I would like R to automatically stop the e-mail if a certain condition is met: for example, check if sales of product x are below 500 Euro and if this is TRUE, do not run the following code.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Just wrap your code in an `if` condition, something like:  `if (sales >= 500 ) { mycode } else { NULL }`